# How do I process a custom input field in Django?

Tags: python, django, api, admin, custom-fields

So here's the scenario.  We have a media page that handles all of our media, most of which we store on our servers.  We outsource the video, however, so I need to be able to add a custom file upload field that connects to the video service's servers through their API.

So I have an admin model for the add media page.  And I have added a file upload field to the page.  When I submit the page, I want all of the fields in our database to update as normal, but I also want to connect with our video service, send the video over to them, get the response, and update our records with the proper key for the video.

So basically, this is a workflow question.  Rather than just:

**request --> validate --> store**

I would like to:

**request --> validate --> connect to API --> upload --> get key --> store**

But I don't know how to add in those additional steps in between the validation and store steps.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You could override your model's or your `ModelForm`'s `save` method and do whatever pre-processing you need before calling the parent class' `save` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save function of form. Since you haven't provided any code, Hope this helps

```
class my_form(forms.Form):
     #code

     #override save function
     def save(self, commit=True, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
          ret = super(my_form, self).save(commit = False, *args, **kwargs)

          #your code

          if commit:
              ret.save()
```